# laravel 6 Socialite notwork

Tags: php, laravel, facebook

i got that problem when i try to make login with facebook **No Socialite driver was specified.**

this is my Route code

```
Route::get('/redirect/{service}', 'SocialiteController@redirect');

Route::get('/callback/{service}', 'SocialiteController@callback');
```

**my Controller functions**

```
class SocialiteController extends Controller
{
  public function redirect($service)
  {
      return Socialite::drive($service)->redirect();
  }
  public function callback($service)
  {
      return $user = Socialite::with($service)->user();
  }
}
```

**and this is my env code**

```
FB_CLIENT_ID = (here id)
FB_CLIENT_SECRET = (here passowrd)
FB_REDIRECT = (here url)
```

**and this is my services code**

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => env('FB_CLIENT_ID'),
    'secret' => env('FB_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'region' => env('FB_REDIRECT')

 ],
```

**html url**

```
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
     <a href="{{url('redirect/Facebook')}}">Login With Facebook</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: you are not calling the `driver` method any where here

Comment: i call it on redirect function

Comment: you always need to call it ... but you are not calling that method based on your code above

Comment: return Socialite::drive($service)->redirect(); 

i call it here

Comment: right which is not the `driver` method .... amazing :(

Answer (score 0):

write facebook lowercase . like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
 <a href="{{url('redirect/facebook')}}">Login With Facebook</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo. it should be `driver` instead of `drive` in the controller, and change the url facebook to lowercase as suggested by @hamed.sz